# payload does not pass when calling action (vuex) - TypeError: Cannot read property 'userDetails' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component UserSettingsGeneral.vue with:

```
<template>
   <vx-card no-shadow>
        <vs-input
            v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces|min:3'"
            data-vv-validate-on="blur"
            name="username"
            class="w-full"
            label-placeholder="Username"
            v-model="username" />
        <span class="text-danger text-sm">{{ errors.first('username') }}</span>

    <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end">
        <vs-button class="ml-auto mt-2" :disabled="!validateForm" @click="updateUser">Save Changes</vs-button>
    </div>
   </vx-card>
</template>
```

and on click Save changes button I call method "updateUser":

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            username: this.$store.state.AppActiveUser.username,
        }
    },
    methods: {
       updateUser () {

            const payload = {
                userDetails: {
                    username: this.username
                },
            }

            console.log('updateUser method from UserSettingsGeneral - payload: ' + payload)

            this.$vs.loading()

            this.$store.dispatch('auth/updateUser')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.$vs.loading.close()
                    this.$vs.notify({
                        time: 10000,
                        title: 'Update Success',
                        text: response.message.data.message,
                        iconPack: 'feather',
                        icon: 'icon-success-circle',
                        color: 'success'
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.$vs.loading.close()
                    this.$vs.notify({
                        time: 6000,
                        title: 'User Update Error',
                        text: error.message,
                        iconPack: 'feather',
                        icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                        color: 'danger'
                    })
                })
        },
    }
```

In console I can see payload as "object Object", but after calling this.$store.dispatch('auth/updateUser') payload is empty.

File auth/moduleAuthActions.js has updateUser action:

```
updateUser( { commit }, payload) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        jwt.updateUser(payload.userDetails.username)
            .then(response => {

                if (response.status == 401) {
                    reject({message: response.data.error})
                }

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', payload.userDetails, {root: true})
                    resolve({message: response})
                }

                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => { reject(error) })
    })
},
```

And now I'm getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'userDetails' of undefined, because there is no payload (empty) here: jwt.updateUser(payload.userDetails.username)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your payload is correct. Only issue is you are not passing that payload when you call dispatch.

Please update action dispatch as below in `updateUser` method:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('auth/updateUser', payload)
```

Comment: Hi @SebastianDratwa please accept this answer so others can find it as a correct answer